# How To Have Multiple Axios inside UseEffect That Doesnt Turn Error?

Tags: reactjs, express, axios, fetch-api, use-effect

I need 3 axios :

1. to detect token, so I know which user is logged in. This is so that I can have a "userid" that I can pass for my other axios endpoints
2. the list of orders : returns an array of all the order history of that user
3. the data of the user, such as first_name, last_name, email etc

here is how it looks like:

```
 const cookies = new Cookies();
  const token = cookies.get("jwtToken");
  const [user_detail, setuser_detail] = useState({});
  const [userid, setuserid] = useState(null);


  const [refresh, setrefresh] = useState(false);

  const [orderData, setorderData] = useState([]);
  const [userData, setuserData] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(`http://localhost:3001/auth/token/decode/${token}`)
      .then((result) => {
        setuser_detail(result.data.user_detail);
        setuserid(result.data.user_detail.user_id);
        setrefresh(!refresh);
      });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(`http://localhost:3001/users/orders/${userid}`)
      .then((res) => {
        setorderData(res.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));

    axios.get(`http://localhost:3001/users/detail/${userid}`).then((res) => {
      setuserData(res.data[0]);
    });
  }, [refresh]);
```

If there is only the useEffect for Token and Orders, it works fine. However when I added the 3rd (user details) useEffect, it doesn't seem to want to receive the response. It will show only if I saved my react file, and then (without restarting my npm start) add the 3rd useEffect. It works until I refresh it, and it returns "TypeError: Cannot read property 'first_name' of undefined". Which doesn't make sense because if I don't refresh it, the first_name can in fact be rendered. I am pretty confused.

Answer (score 1):

Use a single useEffect for onComponentMount, and create an async function inside your useEffect to handle your axios calls.

```
useEffect(() => {
  async callAxios() => {
    const result = await axios.get(`${url_one}`)
    const user_orders = await axios.get(`${url_two}`)
    const user_details = await axios.get(`${url_three}`)
  }
  callAxios()
}, [])
```